# How to Load the UserControl in to Dockpanel Dynamically...in wpf

Tags: wpf, events, delegates

I am using the `RibbonWindow`, and in the first section I am using
ribbonBar buttons and other controls, and in second section I used `DockPanel`
to Show / Load the Other Controls

I have two userControls, one is to display the details using `TextBox`
and `DropDown` controls and another userControl is to show all the
existing data in DataGrid..

These two controls have to be placed in that DockPanel based on
Condition, which is in `RibbonWindow`...

Now, what I want here is when I click on the any of the Grid row, I
need to fill that selected GridRow data into the DisplayUserControl
(userControl1) and that userControl has to load (replace the second
userControl) into that DockPanel...

What I have done is....

First I load the `UserControl2` in to `Dockpanel` of the
`RibbonWindow` and fill the Grid data

and I have taken the Values of the Grid Row using the ClickEvent
(`GridList_MouseDoubleClick()`)

and in that Method I have called One DelegateEvent to call the Method
declared in MainRibbonWindow...

That method is supposed to show the `DockPanel` and load another userControl. The code is below.

the below method is in MainRibbonWindow...

```
public void fnDisplayEmployeeDetails(string str,DockPanel dockPannel)
{
    //  dockPannel is to be cleared...
     this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { dockPannel.Children.Clear(); }, null);  //To Clear the Dock Panel

    CtlAddEmployee frm2 = new CtlAddEmployee(str); //userControl1 and here str is Id of the Row...

    dockPannel.Children.Add(frm2);

}
```

Here all the work is done, but the `DockPanel` remains with the
second userControl only (I.e Displaying Grid only). The dockpanel not
replaced with the firstUserControl

If I am trying to display those same values in another Window's
Dockpanel, it is displaying fine. I don't know why this strange
behaviour is happening...

```
public void fnDisplayEmployeeDetails(string str,DockPanel docPannel)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { docPannel.Children.Clear(); }, null);  //To Clear the Dock Panel

    CtlAddEmployee frm2 = new CtlAddEmployee(str);
    MainWindow mnWindow = new MainWindow();    //another window Form...
    mnWindow.MainWindowDock.Children.Add(frm2);
    mnWindow.ShowDialog();  //here it is showing well....
}
```

How should I show the Details of the Grid values in another usercontrol, and that usercontrol has to be filled in same Dockpanel....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NOT delegating the addition of the child control?  I have found that these behaviour can occur when you access UI components from different threads.  In the case of the different window (second test that worked), since the new window is created in that new thread, the interaction work fine....